# Numpy's linalg.norm() returning 0 on non-zero-vector?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a numpy array of size 268800. I am using this array as an input vector for a backpropagation algorithm, and I wanted to normalize it. Something strange happens when I try though; the magnitude of the vector returns as 0, and I get the error:

```
Backpropagator.py:56: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  x = input.x/np.linalg.norm(input.x)
Backpropagator.py:56: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  x = input.x/np.linalg.norm(input.x)
```

What I don't understand is how this could happen mathematically. If we're taking the Euclidean norm of an n-dimensional vector, the *only* case in which the norm can be 0 is when the vector is the Zero Vector.

However the vector I'm operating on is not a zero-vector, as you can clearly see [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ephraimrothschild/159ac5336d87aa071b4c/raw/d75710c405cb4f829ff58df88f580a43dd0f3e51/np-array).

[image]

[image]

And strangely, the same problem occers when I use Numpy's `dot()` method.

[image]

**So what could possibly be causing numpy to return a norm of 0 on a vector that is not even close to the Zero Vector?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array dtype is uint8.  That type only handles ints between 0 and 255 inclusive:

```
>>> arr = np.array([255,255,255], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> arr
array([255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
>>> arr + 1
array([0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

And so

```
>>> arr.dot(arr)
3
>>> (arr.dot(arr))**0.5
1.7320508075688772
>>> np.linalg.norm(arr)
1.7320508
>>> arr[0]*arr[0]
1
>>> arr[0]*arr[0] + arr[1]*arr[1] + arr[2]*arr[2]
3
```

If you want a different result, change the dtype to something broader, either explicitly or implicitly:

```
>>> np.linalg.norm(arr*1.0)
441.67295593006372
```